# how to arrange a list from backward to forward

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to change the first element by the last, the second element by the last but one, etc..
Then I want to print this.

My list: 
`x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
 I want this list as: 
 `y = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`

how can I do it in Python 3.x?

Comment: Try `x.reverse()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is the following:

```
y = x[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reversed` such as ,

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(list(reversed(x)))
```

output:

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```